# the id of the element won't change in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

i.e.

```
$("#savenew").live('click', function(e)  {
               var user=<?php echo $user?>;
                 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "actions/sub.php",
                data:{user: user} ,
                success: function(){
                  $('#savenew').html('<span>Unsubscribe</span>');
    $(this).attr('id', 'clean'); // this my problem my problem
                        }
            });
     });
```

the id after the ajax request, is not changing from savenew to clean, but the html is perfectly fine, so i know the ajax request is working. what do u thiunk the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to save the `context` (via the [`context` option for `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) so `this` still refers to `#savenew`, like this:

```
$("#savenew").live('click', function(e)  {
  var user=<?php echo $user?>;
  $.ajax({
    context: this, //add this!
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions/sub.php",
    data:{user: user} ,
    success: function(){
      $(this).attr('id', 'clean').html('<span>Unsubscribe</span>');
    }
  });
});
```

Also note that this allows you to chain and clean things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` inside `success: function(){` does not refer to `$('#savenew')`.

As you do in the line above, you need to reference it by id:

```
$('#savenew').attr('id', 'clean');
```

Comment: @getaway - While you *can* do this, it's far less efficient, why run the selector twice more when you already have the element? :)

Comment: Yes, you can chain the calls on $('#savenew'). Of course a more maintenable and reusable solution like Nick's (use of context) is better.